# Всегда ли на сайтах, сохраняющих состояние, используются базы данных?

Tags: база-данных, архитектура, любой-язык

Если на сайте есть возможность регистрации и входа, то обязательно ли где-то на бэкенде используется хотя бы одна база данных?

Comment: Можно даже немного расширить вопрос. "Если на сайте есть возможность регистрации и входа, то обязательно ли они где либо используются в бэкенде?" :)

Comment: нет. не обязательно. можно сделать вполне полноценный сайт без какой-либо бд. да и совсем без сервера приложений.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, без сервера о_0?

Comment: @Aid почитайте про serverless. можно даже сторонние сервисы не использовать.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, и что? В конечном итоге сервер будет, пусть спрятанный провайдером под кучей слоёв абстракции.

Comment: @Aid я же написал: без сторонних сервисов.

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, тогда непонятно - где хоститься сайт будет?

Comment: @Aid на пример на S3 или в другом аналогичном хранилище. все, что нужно - это место где можно хранить статические файлы с доступом по http(s).

Comment: @MikhailVaysman, Видимо, Вы забыли что нужен изменяющийся и сохраняющий состояния сайт.

Comment: @Aid не забыл. один вариант вам уже сказали - куки.

Answer (score 2):

Упорядоченная структура данных, к которой обращаются для восстановления некого состояния - уже БД.
Пусть даже это INI-файл.

Без неё [БД] невозможно восстановить/сохранить данные регистрации, поэтому ответ - да, БД в какой-либо форме для регистрации обязательна.

Answer (score 1):

Существует по крайней мере один вариант, когда при возможности регистрации и входа не будет ни одной упорядоченной структуры, которую можно было бы назвать базой данных. Это превью, который показывают клиенту. Там можно пощелкать кнопочки, порегистрироваться, и даже войти под зарегистрированным именем. Но не факт, что это все уже будет реализовано в бэкенде.

Comment: Очень интересно, можно пример?

Comment: @Aid, вы никогда не видели не видели "превьюх", "прототипов" и т.д. на которых обсуждается будущий функционал с заказчиком. Или у вас все было только на бумаге. [Google](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5+%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0)

Comment: Сильно сомневаюсь что в "регистрацию/вход" там можно считать настоящими. Вшитые данные - это статика.

Comment: @Aid, да зачем же вшитые. Просто куки. У каждого пользователя свои, как следствие никакой упорядоченной структуры нет, никакой связи с бэкендом нет. Но показать клиенту как что будет работать можно, обучать будущих пользователей тоже можно, разместить во внутрикорпоративной  сети тоже на раз.

Comment: Т. е. кукисы - это не упорядоченная структура данный, по которой можно воссоздать что-то из прошлого? Бросьте, они тоже БД. Своеобразная.

Comment: @Aid, базой данных они были бы, если бы, между ними была хоть какая то связность, так как они хранятся на клиенте, то никакой связности между ними нет. Но даже если трактовать БД так широко как вы... обратите внимание на вопрос. :)